# Parallelize by new line?

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have a string `"Hello, World\nHow are you today?"`

I would like `sc.parallelize("Hello, World\nHow are you today?").collect()` to return  `Array("Hello World", "How are you today?")`

Instead, it returns an Array where every character is a separate element.

How would I be able to parallelize a string by new line instead of by character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case I'd normally just do something like:

```
sc.parallelize(myString.split("\n")).collect()
```

if you indeed already have a big string in-memory that has newlines inside it.

The more common case if using Spark is to deal with more data than would be convenient to be already in-memory as a blob, in which case if you have a file containing the data, `sc.textFile` automatically uses newlines as a separator by default:

```
sc.textFile("file:///home/user/mydata.txt").collect()
```

where `mydata.txt` might look like:

```
Hello World
How are you today?
```